# Find a real valued function $u(z)$ which is harmonic in an open disk and continuous up to boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, complex-numbers, harmonic-functions

The radius of disk is said to be $R$, and on the boundary 
$$u(Re^{i\theta})=\dfrac{1}{2}(1+\cos^3\theta).$$

My thought was to integrate it using Poisson kernel, 
$$u(re^{i\theta})=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{R^2-r^2}{R^2-2Rr\cos(\theta-t)+r^2}\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos^3\theta)dt.$$

However, I have trouble integrate this term. Can you suggest me another way of looking at this problem through complex analysis, partial differential equations or some skills in dealing with this integral?

Answer (score 1):

One trick is to recall the Poisson kernel on the unit disc can be written as
$$
P(z)=\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)\text{ for }z\in\mathbb{D}
$$
and you can do the integral that way.  However, it is easier if you just "spot" the answer.

Rescale to $R=1$.  Then
$$
u(e^{i\theta})-\frac12=\frac{\cos^3\theta}{2}=\frac{2\cos(3\theta)+6\cos\theta}{16}
$$
so
$$
u(z)=\frac12+\frac{z^3+\bar{z}^3+3z+3\bar{z}}{16}=\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac12+\frac{z^3+3z}{8}\right).
$$
Rescale back to general $R$ gives
$$
u(z)=\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac12+\frac{z^3+3R^2z}{8R^3}\right)
$$
as the desired harmonic function

Comment: Thanks for your "spotting trick"! However, I am not so sure why $P(z)$ can help me integrate better? I assume that doing line integral, we have to finally go down to the definition $\int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\gamma^'(t)dt$. That's is where I am struggling.

Comment: This form of $P(z)$ (and similar expression for $u(z)$ for $|z|=1$) turns the integral into the form $$\int_\mathbb{T} F(z,\bar{z})\,\mathrm{d}z$$ which is of course equal to $\int_\mathbb{D}\frac{\partial F}{\partial\bar{z}}\,\mathrm{d}\bar{z}\wedge\mathrm{d}z$ by Stoke's/Green's/whatever, i.e., $-2i\iint_\mathbb{D}\partial_{\bar{z}} F\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$ and you can do this by polar coordinates.